# How to use track by using angularJs directive ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data from backend `userList`but its not displaying in table any idea what is implemented wrong in below code using `ng-repeat`.

main.html

```
 <tr ng-repeat="user in userList track by $index">
    <td st-ratio="20">{{user.attuid}}</td>
    <td st-ratio="30">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
    <td st-ratio="15" ng-bind-html="user.type"></td>
    <td st-ratio="15">{{user.email}}</td>
    <td st-ratio="20" class="text-right">
      <button tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-popup-delay="300" uib-tooltip="Edit" type="button" ng-click="editUser($index, user)" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
      </button>
      <button tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-popup-delay="300" uib-tooltip="Delete" ng-disabled="currentUser.id === user._id" type="button" ng-click="deleteUser($index, user)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.userList = data
```

data printing in console

```
Array[1]
0
:
Object
__v
:
0
_id
:
"585419276bef8729e8e4d08e"
attuid
:
"sh89u"
email
:
"sh9829u@gmail.com"
firstName
:
"Syed"
lastName
:
"Hussain"
```

Comment: Are you using a directive or is it just a controller? Have you used an `ng-controller` somewhere in your template if you're just using the controller?

Comment: this data is for bootstrap modal instance where i have specified the controller

Comment: You still need to specify how the controller is injected into the template. If you're using the `controllerAs` syntax, you need to set this in your `ng-repeat`:
`<tr ng-repeat="user in MyCtrl.userList track by $index">`

Comment: there is an issue with ng-repeat i dont its a controller injection problem once ou specify controller in parent for modal instances

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: not authorize on these sites

Comment: The issue that occurs here is that `userList` is being retrieved, but Angular doesn't know where to get it from. You will need to specify how the controller is being injected (could be just `$ctrl` if you're not using the `controllerAs` syntax.